# How do you create a new DateTime since Ecto.DateTime was deprecated?

Tags: elixir

I currently have a `Date` and a `Time` that I would really like to combine into a `DateTime` struct.

Prior to Ecto 3 you could do this with `Ecto.DateTime.from_date_and_time` but in the new documentation since the Ecto Types were deprecated I can't find an equivalent function.

The function currently looks like:

```
def add_datetime(date_as_string) do
 (_, date = Date.from_iso8601(date)
 end_time = #T[23:59:59]

 datetime = datetime_add(Ecto.DateTime.from_date_and_time(date, end_time), -3, "day")
end
```

One of the constraints of this particular project is that I would like to avoid adding a third party library like Timex if at all possible but I am lost after looking at the current Elixir documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime.from_iso8601/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/DateTime.html#from_iso8601/2).

```
datetime_iso8601 = "#{Date.to_iso8601(date)}T#{Time.to_iso8601(time)}+03:30"
{:ok, datetime, offset_from_utc} = DateTime.from_iso8601(datetime_iso8601)
```

Instead of `+3:30` use your desired offset, or `Z` for UTC.

Comment: That worked superbly.Would you mind editing the answer to add the 'T' needed to make it a legal `DateTime`? so `"#{Date.to_iso8601(date)}T#{Time.to_iso8601(time)}+03:30"` then I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this on Google you can also use a `NaiveDateTime` if you don't care about the timezone information:

```
datetime= NaiveDateTime.new(date_struct, time_struct)
|> DateTime.from_naive("Etc/UTC")
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`DateTime.new/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#new/4):

```elixir
iex(1)> DateTime.new(~D[2022-11-19], ~T[21:49:00])
{:ok, ~U[2022-11-19 21:49:00Z]}
```

You can also specify the time zone, if you set up a [time zone database](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#module-time-zone-database):

```elixir
iex(2)> Mix.install [:tz]
iex(3)> Calendar.put_time_zone_database(Tz.TimeZoneDatabase)
iex(4)> DateTime.new(~D[2022-11-19], ~T[21:49:00], "Asia/Tokyo")
{:ok, #DateTime<2022-11-19 21:49:00+09:00 JST Asia/Tokyo>}
```